# Does nmbd binds on a IPv6-Only network?

Tags: samba, ipv6

After moving my Samba to a IPv6-Only environment, nmbd doesn't start up anymore...

I tried this:

`interfaces = 2001:db8:1:1::/64`

and with this:

`bind interfaces only = yes`...

But, nmbd doesn't starts up, the log.nmbd shows:

```
[2014/04/21 03:36:38,  3] ../lib/util/util_net.c:70(interpret_string_addr_internal)
   interpret_string_addr_internal: getaddrinfo failed for name 0.0.0.0 [Address family for hostname not supported]
```

Any tips?! I'm totally newbie with Windows/Samba things and I don't even know if nmbd in fact, works with IPv6...

BTW, smbd works okay in a IPv6-Only environment, shares are working and, `smbclient -L fileserver -N` shows:

```
fileserver is an IPv6 address -- no workgroup available
```

This is because of nmbd is now, obsolete?

I'm thinking that nmbd have nothing to do with IPv6, am I right?

Using Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Cheers!
Thiago

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
hints.ai_flags = flags
```

with

```
hints.ai_flags = flags & ~AI_ADDRCONFIG;
```

in `lib/util/util_net.c` file of Samba. Compile and run the samba in only IPV6 environment.